# Clang compiling for iOS (arm64) with -shared LDFLAG - Exec format error

Tags: c++, ios, clang, clang++, jailbreak

Newbie alert here, sorry in advance if this question duplicates (didn't find the answer elsewhere)!

I run into problems with simple hello binary for iOS (arm64) build on macOS machine (x86_64).

The problem is that when I add LDFLAGS with shared framework (i.e. "-shared -framework CoreMedia" or other framework) to build my binary, it compiles fine but when it executes on device I get **`Exec format error`**:

```
iPhone:/tmp root# ./hello 
-sh: ./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Build without `-shared` flag it runs as intended:

```
iPhone:/tmp root# ./hello 
Hello
```

Can someone please explain to me why this flag causes exec error on binary? Is it related to different platform which I'm building on than the targeted device?

Should I build on arm64 platform to get `-shared` flag working fine?

Just in case, build script is:

```
export CLANG_BIN=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang`
export CLANGXX_BIN=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang++`
export SDK=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`

export CFLAGS="-fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/ -fno-stack-protector -Wno-builtin-requires-header -fno-stack-check"
#export LDFLAGS="-shared -framework CoreMedia" # <- exec error when this added to compile
export LDFLAGS="-framework CoreMedia" # <- with just this, bin executes fine

export CXX="$CLANGXX_BIN $CFLAGS -isysroot $SDK"

$CXX -arch arm64 -o hello hello.c $LDFLAGS -Wall -Wconversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-shared` means you're building a shared library.
You cannot run a shared library.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I thought that -shared flag is related to linked framework not to the whole compile output